# how to log failed login attempts (bruteforce attack prevention)

Tags: security, web, brute-force

I'm currently searching for the best way to prevent my software's webportal from bruteforce attacks and came up with the following idea:

```
- 3 login attempts without any visual change
- after 3 failed attempts show Google reCaptcha
- allow another 3 attempts but now you have to click the captcha every time
- if the last 3 attempts failed again lock the account
```

My idea just has major downsides and I hope you could give some advice:

- what happens if the username changes at every login attempt? which account do I lock after 6 attempts?
- how shall I log the 3 failed attempts before showing the captcha?

  - IP? But what if lot's of people from a company network use the software at once?
  - Browser user agent? What if someone who tries the bruteforce attack simply changes the user agent at every login attempt?
  - Cookies?

Comment: Please don't cross post https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102467/my-bruteforce-prevention-has-major-downsides-any-ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, a few considerations, followed by some suggestions at the end.**

Remember, brute force can generally be successful, but its a matter of time.  So, its a matter of you making that amount of time **unattainable** as much as possible.

Therefore, it starts way before you are dealing with the brute-force attach such as forcing users to implement [higher standard passwords](http://blog.codinghorror.com/your-password-is-too-damn-short/) (e.g. phrases and 12+ character passwords, etc...)

Then, there isn't always a one-size fits all solution, so the first order of business is to really define who your intended audience is or will be.

1. I will say that usually a lockout measure can sound great but have extreme negative affects such as allowing attackers to force a denial of services to your users by inevitably locking legit users out of their accounts.

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks) lists a number reasons not to implement a lockout solution:

- An attacker can cause a denial of service (DoS) by locking out large numbers of accounts.
- Because you cannot lock out an account that does not exist, only
  valid account
- names will lock. An attacker could use this fact to harvest usernames
  from the site, depending on the error responses.
- An attacker can cause a diversion by locking out many accounts and
  flooding the help desk with support calls.
- An attacker can continuously lock out the same account, even seconds
  after an administrator unlocks it, effectively disabling the account.
- Account lockout is ineffective against slow attacks that try only a
  few passwords every hour.
- Account lockout is ineffective against attacks that try one password
  against a large list of usernames.
- Account lockout is ineffective if the attacker is using a
  username/password combo list and guesses correctly on the first
  couple of attempts.
- Powerful accounts such as administrator accounts often bypass lockout
  policy, but these are the most desirable accounts to attack. Some
  systems lock out administrator accounts only on network-based logins.
- Even once you lock out an account, the attack may continue, consuming
  valuable human and computer resources.

However, I think you have some reasonable ideas that can be expounded upon such as:

1. Using Google's reCaptcha (like you suggested).
2. Imposing a delaying mechanism on each unsuccessful attempt (or early on e.g. 2nd, 3rd attempt..)
3. Consider some identification mechanism to impose the reCaptcha such as browser [fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes) or IP address for non-thin clients.
4. Despite the fact that they use a different username/password, you can still track unsuccessful attempts, and at some number of failed attempts (1, 2, 3...whatever) impose a reCaptcha and delay.  So if they retry a same username before a successful login has occurred, they will encounter those restrictions.
5. A possible BFD (Brute Force Detection) system that can help identify when one is actually occurring.

If you were to use IP addresses as identification, legit users of the same network (external IP address) to be subjugated to a reCapchta and/or delay would only be affected if it was their username that was tried unsuccessful. But if you aren't locking out accounts, then the most they are going to entail is a recaptcha and/or short delay.

But at the end of the day, a brute-force attack that is re-routing IP address and changing username/password on each attempt is not any different necessarily than a high traffic site with legitimate users.  It would just appear (possibly) as having a higher number of failed attempts in **retrospect**.